# How to upload image of bigger size in mysql database using php in android

Tags: php, android

hello everyone I m making an android app to upload image in mysql db using php and it working properly.Application uploading the image to database successfully but the problem is that i can only upload image of smaller size only in kbs.I want it to upload the image in mbs.I try everthing but nothing works till now.plz somebody help me...
 my code for uploading the image in php is:

```
 <?php



 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $photo= $_POST['photo'];
    $bookname=$_POST['bookname'];
            $phoneNumber=$_POST['phoneNumber'];
            $price=$_POST['price'];

    require_once('loginConnect.php');

    $sql ="SELECT id FROM images ORDER BY id ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $id = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $id = $row['id'];
    }



             $path = "uploads/$id.png";
    $actualpath = "http://www.bsservicess.com/photoUpload/$path";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (photo,bookname,phoneNumber,price) VALUES
  ('$actualpath','$bookname','$phoneNumber','$price')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($photo));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

And my android activity for uploading the image is:

```
 package com.manali.vivek.userregistration;

  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.MediaStore;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.util.Base64;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.HashMap;


public class image extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener 
{

public static final String UPLOAD_URL =  
 "http://www.bsservicess.com/photoUpload/uploadImage.php";
public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "photo";

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
private Button buttonView;

private ImageView imageView;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Uri filePath;
    EditText et1, et2, et3;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonViewImage);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
    et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);




}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 
    PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent
 data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data
!= null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),
        filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();


    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}


private void uploadImage() {


    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(image.this, "Uploading Image",
  "Please wait...", true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {

            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);
            String bookname = et1.getText().toString();
            String phoneNumber = et2.getText().toString();
            String price = et3.getText().toString();

            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);

            data.put(Fetch.BOOK_NAME, bookname);
            data.put(Fetch.PHONE_NUMBER, phoneNumber);
            data.put(Fetch.PRICE, price);


            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, data);

            return result;
        }

    }

    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();

    ui.execute(bitmap);

 }


@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if (v == buttonUpload) {
        uploadImage();
    }


    if (v == buttonView) {
        viewImage();
    }
}


private void viewImage() {
    startActivity(new Intent(image.this, Main.class));
}


  ///////toolbar

  }
```

Comment: check what the max upload size is set to in your system

Comment: file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 400M
upload_max_filesize = 500M 
memory_limit = 128M  thats  what is given in my php.ini

Comment: hey buddy plz help me.I already wasted so many days.

Answer (score 0):

whats the datatype of column you are storing the base64? try text or blob.. maybe the text is too long for datatype to handle. wild guess only

Comment: thanx for the answer i use varchar to upload the image, now did i have to change it to the text.

Comment: please mark it as answer if it solved your answer thanks :D